# wp_nav_menu_objects with pre_get_posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to query the posts based on my navigation menu.
i.e I take the object id of the first item in navigation menu and want to query posts in that way,

Here are the Codes.

To Get first Item from Navigation Menu

```
 function get_theme_item( $theme_location ) {
     if( ! $theme_location ) return false;

     $theme_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
     if( ! isset( $theme_locations[$theme_location] ) ) return false;

     $menu_obj = get_term( $theme_locations[$theme_location], 'nav_menu' );
     if( ! $menu_obj ) return false;

    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_obj->term_id);
    foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
      $qid = $menu_item->object_id;
        break;
     }
     return $qid;
}
```

Well, this works flawlessly and returns the id of first menu item.

Querying posts code:

```
 function p_query_posts($query) {
    $id = get_theme_item('header_menu');
 if (  $query->is_main_query() && is_front_page() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'album_post' ) );
      $taxquery = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'album',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array($id)
        )
    );

$query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
}

return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','p_query_posts');
```

PROBLEM:
This gives me an 500 Internal server error, without displaying any error. 
if i change `$id` to 12 , ie `$id = '12'`, it works properly.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try echo $id, to verify if it contain data..

Comment: Already tried, it returns 12 properly

Comment: Where you set $id = '12';?
Here? 'terms' => array('12')

Comment: can you get detailed error from the web server error log? you can find the exact reason there.

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem, removing  `get_theme_item('header_menu')` function from pre_get_posts, and using $id='12' works properly

Comment: have you tried `$id=12` instead of `$id='12'`?

Comment: Yeah, that also works @bansi

Comment: pre_get_posts are called after nav_menus are loaded, if i guess, so why it turns to be so early? @PieterGoosen

Comment: Sorry, my last comment did not go through and that one did not get deleted, crap. What I wanted to say is `get_theme_item()` returns false in all probability for some reason.  Have you tested the result from that function inside your `pre_get_posts` action

Comment: no, including that functions returns false,
I am thinking to use WP_Query instead